# Using sql Server 2008 Express How to use "@" inserting an email add. in a record

Tags: sql

I am getting errors while trying to insert an email address in a record. I think they are related to the @ symbol.

Is there something special I need to do with the @ symbol?

Comment: Please post a specific example of an insert.  There's nothing special about an @ enclosed in quotes (as all strings must be).

Comment: Hi Joe,
I am new at this, having trouble deciphering the error codes but I think this is part of it.

INSERT Employees (Email) SELECT 'msmith@company.net'
INSERT Employees (Email) SELECT 'dwarren@company.net'
INSERT Employees (Email) SELECT 'ezip@company.net'
INSERT Employees (Email) SELECT 'tblank@company.net'
INSERT Employees (Email) SELECT 'mzag@company.net'

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 Express

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near '_Code'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 57
Incorrect syntax near '_Code'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 58
Error codes look like this


Incorrect syntax near '_Code'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 59
Incorrect syntax near '_Code'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 60

Answer (score 1):

The variable you store the string into can be preceded by an @ to take it "literally" or "verbatim"

such as

```
String myEmail;

myEmail = @"test@email.com";

...
```

Although I must admit, I've only needed the literal when dealing with file system paths, not email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string concatenation to do it then you will get errors... the ampersand is used to indicate a parameter. Can you post more info (ie. sample code, errors, programming language)?